# Unable to build xgboost with OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, osx-elcapitan, xgboost

I am trying to build xgboost on mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6, however, it's giving me unsupported option '--fopenmp'

`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 1`

I have updated Xcode and gcc using brew, and have gcc version as

`gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 6.2.0 --without-multilib' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 (Homebrew gcc 6.2.0 --without-multilib)`

Please let me know if I am missing anything which is causing error while building xgboost. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to install it is using the `build.sh` script in the root of the repository.

This will disable OpenMP support if it is not available (for example in Mac)

Or

Copy `make/minimum.mk` as `config.mk` to manually disable openmp support

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this option, it shows the progress with -fopenmp flag and fails. Continues with single thread xgboost and went through till end with some warnings, no error. Then I went in python shell and tried to import xgboost but it fails. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah, well the instructions here are to compile the C binary (You can run it with the binary `xgboost` in the folder of xgboost. To install the Python package, more steps needed: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#python-package-installation

Comment: I was dumb to miss that step and now it's working fine for me. Thank you very much :)